# Get data into MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to populate a javascript function with some information from my DB, is the best way to access via the controller and pass it through(I'm not sure how to pass an object) or is it easier to have the view to retrieve the data?

i have to create an object in javascript something like this

```
new FleetSelector([{ "OwnerId": "2df3893d-c406-48fe-8443-1622ddc51af2", "DisplayName": "Navman Dev" }, { "OwnerId": "7A402CD7-5EEA-4AF5-80A3-22EED0610C9D", "DisplayName": "CORSA TRANSPORTES" }]);
                }
```

so is there a way to pass an list of objects that i can loop through in my view to be able to make that javascript?

Comment: What does your controller and view look like?

Comment: You can access model directly in Javascript from the View in MVC. MyFunction(@Model) {};

Comment: In case you are using jquery, then you could have a http request fire off to your controller, that will go and fetch the data from your database and on return of the request in your jquery success function you will have the data that you can populate in the view. This is one way of doing it. But without knowing too much about your environment and setup ofcourse its not possible to give a practical answer